# MPEG-2 Program Stream w/PCM Audio

Tags: ffmpeg, pcm, mpeg-2

I'm trying to create an MPEG-2 Program Stream in an mpg wrapper that contains PCM audio.  When I run the below command, I get an output that contains MPEG-1 audio.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -vcodec mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -bf 2 -b:v 50000000 -maxrate 50000000 -minrate 50000000 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -acodec pcm_s24be "output.mpg"
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to get the command working to give me PCM in an MPEG-2 PS file with in an mpg wrapper?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Hi Will, in what way is it outside the bounds of discussion?  Thanks.

Comment: Probably because this doesn't have anything to do with software development.

Comment: ffmpeg questions "sometimes" go to superuser instead.  It's quite confusing :|

Comment: I wasn't aware that the bounds of discussion were for software development only.  Seems odd considering the enormous pool of FFMPEG based questions and answers on the site dating back years...

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg only supports muxing 16 bit PCM in a MPEG2 PS. Use

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" \
  -c:v mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -bf 2 -b:v 50M -maxrate 50M -minrate 50M \
  -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 \
  -c:a pcm_s16be -f vob "output.mpg"
```

The `-f vob` is needed to force a MPEG-2 PS, else ffmpeg will select MPEG-1 Systems muxer.

Comment: Thanks Mulvya.  I did find some info on the -f vob tag, but when I tried it, it  changed nothing.  I guess it's because I was encoding 24 bit rather than 16.